# what does "system use case" means?

Tags: uml, tool-uml, argouml, staruml

i searched lately about the menaning of system use cases but i couldn't find anything clear i really couldnt see the point :// ..as far as i know its a use cases modeling where the "System" is one of the actors, but it is not clair enough
i working on a project where the system is doing a big part of work ( GPS, sending android nortification , calculate distance....) i wondering who could i make the system on of my actors ? im going to modeling the use case of syteme apart? 
plz any one could make it clear??
thank u
:))

Comment: Try wikipedia for start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case

Comment: Best suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Use case" and "System Use Case" terms are used interchangeably almost at all times. It has nothing to do with the system as an actor. Use cases in general can be, system use cases or business use cases. Business use cases are used in business modelling and system use cases are used in system requirements engineering.

See this article for more information:

http://www.agileea.com/Whitepapers/All3%20Business%20vs%20System%20Use%20Cases%20v1%209.pdf